# Selecting the vector with the largest sum Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

I'm looking for a way to select the vector that has the largest sum. Is there a simple way of doing this? I was thinking of writing a loop, but I'm not sure how to loop over a set of vectors.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess the vectors all have the same number of elements?How are your data organized? Are they a bunch of individual vectors of vectors making up a big matrix for example?

Comment: Yes, they do, I suppose I could create a matrix from them instead and find the row with the max sum in the matrix, but i'm not sure if that would be easier

Answer (score 1):

For the case in which the vectors have the same length (as stated in the comment), I think a simple loop-free way would be to build  a matrix from each vector and fetch directly the row (or column) with the largest sum:

```
clear
clc

RandMat = rand(8,10);

[~,Ind] = max(sum(RandMat,2)); %// Get row index for largest sum. If you want the column, use 1 instead.
MaxRow = RandMat(Ind,:); %// Index in original matrix to get the vector. If you want the column, use RandMat(:,Ind);
```

If vectors don't have the same length then you would need to pad the missing values with NaN for example to use a regular matrix, otherwise you would need a cell array.

If you prefer a solution in which you don't have to build a matrix then you could loop through each individual vector and store the sum in a variable, then compare the sums at the end. If you would like such a solution please ask!

Comment: @Lia so dis this answer help you solve your problem or you need additional assistance?